# Could not resolve '-fx-tab-border-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule in stylesheet

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

Since my rules are already in place but getting these errors flowlessly. I was trying to understand the solutions available on the web, but none of them worked for me.

```
Jul 18, 2016 1:39:17 PM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-tab-border-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.tab-pane>*.tab-header-area>*.control-buttons-tab' in stylesheet file ***style.css***
```

Getting above mentioned and lot of warnings similar to this, due to which some of the components are not able to load properly. Using Java1.8.0_66.

*root in my css file is like:*

```css
.root {

    -fx-base: #d0d0d0;

    -fx-background: #f4f4f4;

    -fx-control-inner-background: white;
    -fx-font-family:"Courier";
    -fx-font-size: 12;

    -fx-dark-text-color: black;
    -fx-mid-text-color: #292929;
    -fx-light-text-color: white;

    -fx-accent: #0093ff;

    -fx-focus-color: #0093ff;

    -fx-color: -fx-base;

    -fx-disabled-opacity: 0.9;

    -fx-hover-base: ladder(
        -fx-base,
        derive(-fx-base,20%) 20%,
        derive(-fx-base,30%) 35%,
        derive(-fx-base,40%) 50%
     );

    -fx-pressed-base: derive(-fx-base,-20%);

    -fx-focused-base: -fx-base;

    -fx-tab-border-color: -fx-box-border;

    -fx-background-color: inherit;
    -fx-background-radius: inherit;
    -fx-background-insets: inherit;
    -fx-padding: inherit;

    -fx-cell-hover-color: #cce3f4;

    -fx-cell-focus-inner-border: #85b9de;

    -fx-page-bullet-border: #acacac;    
    -fx-page-indicator-hover-border: #accee5;   
}
```

**and it is used from:**

```css
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .control-buttons-tab {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.083333em 0.25em 0.083333em 0.25em; /* 1 3 1 3 */
}
```

is the same css file.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Try to modify `-fx-tab-border-color` to e.g. `TAB_BORDER_COLOR`.

Comment: Works fine for me. You probably shouldn't use the `-fx` prefix for your own looked-up color definitions, but it works just fine.

Comment: @James_D I have mentioned **css** .root content and content of css where it is used in the problem description. And I can see, there is no issue with `-fx`. Same problem I'm facing with `-fx-disabled-opacity`.

Comment: Two people have tried the code you posted and cannot reproduce the error. So it's probably reasonable to assume either that you have an error in the code you are using that is not present in the code you posted, or the error is somehow caused by other parts of your code.

Comment: For `-fx-disabled-opacity`: there is no such property defined in JavaFX CSS, and you can't define "looked-up values" for numeric values in the same way that you can for colors.

Comment: I got what was the issue, actually **Parent** was not the **root** element in my code, i had embedded Parent into pane.

Answer (score 5):

I recently came across this problem as well. Just what 'RAM World' says, this problem occurs when a `Node` is not a root element, but is still accessing the predefined values in the `root` block. A simple solution to this is to widen the scope of the selector so javafx can find the predefined values. e.g.;

```
.root > *
{
    /* add your predefined values here */
}
```

In this case it selects the `root` and every (nested)child of it. I perefer this notation as it makes clear these are root-properties/values. If you want the most shortest notation the following will also work:

```
*
{
    /* add your predefined values here */
}
```

In this case it selects every `Node`.

Although this is/was an old post, hopefully this was helpfull to someone.

---

**EDIT**

Do not use the first method (`root > *`)! when using a dynamic root javafx will still complain about unresolved rules/attributes. Only the second method (`*`) worked for me without errors

Comment: When I used the pure asterix version and override '-fx-font-size' there I'am unable to override the font size anywhere else like in a style-class added to button. I solved this by not overriding the font in * but in a extra defined root style class like .my-root {-fx-font-size:10; }. Then I was able to override the font size in other style classes.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with java code written for launching the application **Parent** was not root element, Parent was nested inside Pane. That's why, it was able to resolve the CSS, this is only seen in FX8, because in javafx2.2, for applying a *css*, it is not mandatory for **Parent** to be actual root element. It works fine in JavaFx2.2, if Parent is not root element.